# I Have three warning in my main function with regards to argument, cast and pointers

Tags: c

"return from incompatible pointer type" [enable by default]".

Please could you explain why this would happen and how i can get around it?

this code has both the main function as well as the addpackets function these are the only two functions with any issues and its all since trying to make the code work with malloc for use of dynamic memory.

Comment: Please ignore the final part about the expected int issue, this is from a separate function.

Comment: Have you added a declaration (prototype) of your functions? In C everything has to be declare before it's used.

Comment: What are your prototypes for addpacket, listpackets and save?

Comment: Ive updated the code to include my prototypes, Ive only had these problems since trying to make the code work with malloc. everything worked fine before that.

Comment: your call to `addpacket` does not match its prototype.

Comment: How come? i only have the first two errors to fix. i just don't understand what is meant by without a cast.

Comment: do like `info = addpacket(&records, info);`

Comment: Please don't fix the code in your question as you find the solution. That way, the problems disappear and the question becomes meaningless.

Comment: ok sorry, i still have issues in my code though haha. ill not update it further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your last warning was from `addpacket()` function.

The `addpacket()` function takes and integer pointer `int*` as first argument, and you are passing an `int` instead.

You need to call `addpacket` as follow:

```
info = addpacket(&records, info);
```

But in your addpacket function, you are returning an integer, so change the return type of the function to int

So change

```
struct packets* addpacket(int *recCount, struct packets *info)
```

to

```
int addpacket(int *recCount, struct packets *info)
```

You also have bugs in your `addpacket` function

while you are doing `records++`, remember records is a pointer not an integer, so you have to use value at operator i.e. `*records++`

also, you should return `*records`

Easiest way to solve all your errors will be to do the following:

change addpacket to as follow:

```
int addpacket(int recCount, struct packets *info)
```

and call it like

```
records = addpacket(records, info);
```

No other change is required in this way.

You have lot to learn about pointers. When I post the code here, please compare it with yours and try to find out the differences and their reasons.

**The reason of your crash is, you are creating only one packet named `info` with `malloc`, and every time you are adding a packet is just overwriting it. But when you display or save, you are trying to access the memory like `info[i]` that is never allocated.** only `info[0]` is present in your code, where did you get the array then?

To fix this, you can omit the `malloc` and use a static array like

```
struct packets info[MAX_COUNT];
```

On the other hand, if you need to dynamically create the packets, best way is to use a linked list. But in that case you have to change your `addpacket` and `listpackets` function accordingly.

**If you do not know about linked lists, start reading about them.**

Comment: Thanks that fixed the third error, just left with the other two.

Comment: I saw you changed the code, but addpacket is returning `struct packets*`, you are still assigning it to `int`.

Comment: yeah that managed to fix that part of the code, the only issues i have remaining are the ones listed above with regards to return incompatible pointer type and assignment makes intiger from pointer without a cast [enable by default].  id be extremely gratful if you could help.

Comment: Thanks very much, this has solved those problems.  although now that is fixed it has just created more flaws in my other two functions which i think could be down to some pointer issues.  when i run my second two functions the programme just crashes.

Comment: Your errors are mostly type mismatch, carefully see all the errors/warnings, you will be able to track down.

Comment: by changing it back to the way i originally had it as you said second is what gave me all the errors originally anyway.  my aim is to use malloc and to be able to validate user input. i think i might be confusing issues by not showing my whole code so i'll update it so all my code is available.  one i call my second and third function it will crash. although i get no errors or warnings.

Comment: best way to give all the functions, and how you call them in main(). It is really a problem to understand if you have errors inside a function

Comment: so that is my full code above, it is error and warning free when comiled although it just crashes but like i said i think this could be a pointer issue.  i have only managed to validate source so far and will work on the rest once the programme actually runs.